# Get data from 3 tables by one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small blog project
I have 3 tables

```
Posts
PostID | TITLE | WRITERS(USERS) | CATEGORIES
1 | SOME TITLE | 1,2 | 1,2

USERS
USERID | USERNAME
1 | Alaa
2 | John

Categories
1 | Business
2 | Marketing
```

I am trying to get this output

```
POST TITLE: SOME TITLE
Writers: Alaa And John
Categories: Business, And marketing
```

Please note that i am talking about a very big loop, 100 post in a page for many viewers
So, currently i have two ideas 
First idea

```
1- take value from writers ( 1,2 )
2- Explode it by php
3- use mysql query to bring the writers
4- Do the same thing for categories
```

Second idea is to remove the columns writers, categories from the posts table and create a fourth table and call it connections, which will refer ids to each others ( connect everything together )
But i don't even know if i can do the mysql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all these values in one MySQL query.

```
SELECT p.TITLE AS `Post Title`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.USERNAME) AS Writers,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.CategoryName) AS Categories
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.USERID, p.WRITERS)
JOIN Categories c ON FIND_IN_SET(c.Id, p.CATEGORIES)
GROUP BY p.TITLE
```

Output:

```
Post Title  Writers     Categories
SOME TITLE  Alaa,John   Business,Marketing
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/67sGFv3xcERojvypmjdF8/0)

**Note:** storing values in comma separated lists (e.g. your `WRITERS` and `CATEGORIES` columns) is a bad idea and makes writing this sort of query problematic (it's only MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function which makes it workable at all) and you should look into properly normalising your data (one value per row). [Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/67sGFv3xcERojvypmjdF8/1) is an example of how your database could look normalised.

Comment: Any advice on how to use the multiple categories/authers? I am thinking about creating fourth table to specific the relations something like this post_id | category_id

Comment: @user3356619 you would need two extra tables, posts_writers and posts_categories. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/67sGFv3xcERojvypmjdF8/1